# numpy indexing with conditional transposes dimensions

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

When I mix mask-indices and normal indices, I get a weird result:

```
a = np.zeros((3,2,5))
cond = [True]*5
print(a[0][:,cond].shape) # prints '(2,5)' as expected
print(a[0,:,cond].shape)  # prints '(5,2)' which is surprising
```

i.e., the resulting array is transposed from what I think should happend

Is this a bug? is this a feature? If someone can point me to a piece of documentation that explains this I would be very glad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. It happens because you have mixed basic indexing (slice) and advanced indexing (integer and boolean array). It's documented [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing):

> Two cases of index combination need to be distinguished:
>
> - **The advanced indexes are separated by a slice, Ellipsis or newaxis. For example x[arr1, :, arr2].**
> - The advanced indexes are all next to each other. For example x[..., arr1, arr2, :] but not x[arr1, :, 1] since 1 is an advanced
>   index in this regard.
>
> **In the first case, the dimensions resulting from the advanced indexing
> operation come first in the result array, and the subspace dimensions
> after that.** In the second case, the dimensions from the advanced
> indexing operations are inserted into the result array at the same
> spot as they were in the initial array (the latter logic is what makes
> simple advanced indexing behave just like slicing).