# What is happening in numpy advanced index containing slice?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have 3d ndarray `a`, created like this:

```
a = np.arange(0, 24).reshape(2, 3, 4)
```

When I run `a[1, [[0, 1], [1, 0]]]`, below is the result.

```
array([[[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]]])
```

I know this is called advanced indexing, and this is happening because `1` and `[[0, 1], [1, 0]]` are broadcasted into `(2, 2)` shape.
The resultant array has `(2, 2, 4)` shape, this reason is also written in doc ([Indexing on ndarrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing))

> In general, the shape of the resultant array will be the concatenation of the shape of the index array (or the shape that all the index arrays were broadcast to) with the shape of any unused dimensions (those not indexed) in the array being indexed.

What I don't understand is the behavior when advanced indexing contains slice. For example, when I run `a[1, 0:1, [[0, 1], [1, 0]]]`, I get below:

```
array([[[12],
        [13]],

       [[13],
        [12]]])
```

The shape is (2, 2, 1). On broadcasting, `1`, `0:1`, `[[0, 1], [1, 0]]` should be indexed into `(2, 2)` indexing array, so I at first thought this resultant array's shape will be `(2, 2)`. But it is actually `(2, 2, 1)`. I want to know the exact rule how resultant array's shape is determined in advanced indexing .

Comment: You first: I don't understand your reasoning for expecting the result that you expect. Please walk through it step by step, so that we can point out exactly where the actual behaviour is different.

Comment: With `0:1` in the middle of other indices you get 'mixed basic and advanced' indexing.  In this case the slice dimension(s) is tacked on to the end.  It is documented on the main indexing page, and discussed several times a year on SO.

Comment: In the first case, `1` selects the second block of `a`, `a[1,:,:]`. The 2nd index selects a (2,2) block from the size 3 dimension (rows).  The `4` is tge columns dimension.  No broadcasting here. In the 2nd case you are selecting the (2,2) 'block' from the last dimension.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68458532/numpy-indexing-with-conditional-transposes-dimensions

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you, I exactly wanted to know the 'mixed basic and advanced' indexing term. It looks like the documentation is already archived (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing), I mostly understand the rule by the link you dropped.

Comment: Ah no, I found it is documented here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing

Comment: I should have checked the link you provided.  It's the `Combining advanced and basic indexing` section 2/3 of the way down.  Not quite as prominent as in some earlier editions, but still there.